# How do I print out all the people in my person object constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
function person(a,b,c) {
 this.firstName = a;
 this.lastName = b;
 this.age = c;
};

var friend = new person("John", "Doe", 25);
var friend2 = new person ("Java", "Script", 20);
var friend3 = new person ("Mike", "Johnson", 26);
```

Essentially what I want to do is to create a database where a user enters their first name, last name, and age. Then I want to print out each user's information on the screen. How do I print out all their information? I tried:  `for(var prop in person) {document.write(person[prop]); };` but that didn't seem to work. Please help, extreme newbie here. Thank you.

Comment: try `for(var prop in friend)`. and don't use document.write

Comment: @charlietfl wont that just print John doe? I want it to print out everybody, no matter how many new people I include.

Comment: put them all in an array then, loop over array and then loop over properties of each element

Comment: Right now, you are not storing created persons in anywhere. If you want to reach them, store them in an array or object. Then you can iterate through it whenever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create an array to contain all the people
var people = [];

// push new people into the array
people.push(new person("John", "Doe", 25));
people.push(new person("Java", "Script", 20));

// create an array to contain our html
var html = [];

// loop over the array of people and add each person's
// information to the html you want to output
for (var i = 0, l = people.length; i < l; i++) {
    var person = people[i];
    for (var p in person) {
        html.push(person[p], '<br/>');
    }
    html.push('<br>');
}

// Add the completed html (using join) to the page
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html.join('');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m11v4bh9/)

Comment: I understand how this works, thank you. But I think I have to ask a brand new question. One that includes the input boxes and all. I want my code to print out all the people no matter how many people the user includes on the page I will create. The only trouble Im having with your code is how will the new person I create have this code `people.push(new person("new", "personIncluded", 25));` included automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You're better off post a new question with all the relevant html and JS.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your `person` objects in a `users` list like so:

```
var users = [];
users.push(friend, code);
users.forEach(function(pers) {
    for(var prop in pers) {
        console.log(pers[prop]); 
    };
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function person(a,b,c) {
 this.firstName = a;
 this.lastName = b;
 this.age = c;

 this.print = function()
 {
    document.write(this.firstName);
    document.write(this.lastName);
    document.write(this.age);
  }
};

var friend = new person("John", "Doe", 25);
 friend.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "person" as a class here. It (person) doesn't has reference of all the object instance created using it. You need to store reference of these instances somewhere to print a list of it. Below is a rough example of how you can do that.

```
function person(a,b,c) {
 person.list = person.list || [];
 person.list.push(this)
 this.firstName = a;
 this.lastName = b;
 this.age = c;
};

var friend = new person("John", "Doe", 25);
var code = new person ("Java", "Script", 20);

for(i in person.list){
    var per = person.list[i];
    document.write("first name: "+per.firstname+" last name: "+per.lastname+ 
       " age: "+per.age);
}
```